# My badges showing great fluctuations

Tags: support, badges, meta

Just now I saw the number of the badges go down from 13 to 5 then back to 13 and for now it shows 6.

Why is this happening?

Also, along with that, the number of people reached and votes cast is also reduced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:** The main site and meta are two different sites, each of them counts badges separately.

One guess how this can be explained is that you sometimes look at your [profile on the main site](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1050858/inanimatebeing) where you have [13 badges](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1050858/inanimatebeing?tab=badges) (at the moment). And if you are on meta, you see the [6 badges earned on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1050858/inanimatebeing?tab=badges).

And, naturally, if you go on some other site (such as [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17930908/inanimatebeing) or [its meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17930908/inanimatebeing)) - you'll see the number of badges that you've earned on that particular site.

Comment: But why is it fluctuating? And just some seconds ago, it even fell down to just 1 badge.

Comment: @InanimateBeing I don't think it is really fluctuating. On meta, you'll see 6 badges until you get next one. (And since you got [commentator badge just recently](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1050858/inanimatebeing?tab=activity&sort=badges), it was 5 badges before that.) Similarly, on the main site you should see 13 badges until you get the next one. (You profile says that [you've earned the most recent one yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1050858/inanimatebeing?tab=activity&sort=badges).)

Comment: @InanimateBeing When you said that "it fell down to one badge", is it possible that you were looking at StackOverflow Meta - after clicking on [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17930908/inanimatebeing)? (Which I provided in the post as an illustration of differences between various sites.)

Comment: I now a lot confused at the moment and as per the answer by @MartinSleziak, things seem okay, so I'll stop at that. But being present here (right here on this webpage only) the fluctuations were observed by me, though not any more and the fluctuations have stopped after being the way they should be as per the answer.

Comment: @InanimateBeing Feel free to [ping me in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2022/6/28) - if we happen to be online at the same time, I'll try whether I might be able to explain better what I mean. (It might be easier if we can interact a bit and I can ask you which site you're viewing when you see 15 badges, 6 badges, etc.)

Comment: As user I'm not facing any problem now and is per your answer, different for different places. As moderator probing possibility of bug, here's what happened: For 24 hrs, I was seeing 13 badges on Math Meta too which is actually on my main account but then suddenly I saw a drop in badges to 5, 1 or 2 mins later, got back to 13, 1 min more and it dropped to 6 now and that's when I quickly typed my post. After 5 mins I even saw a drop to 1 momentarily which as I refreshed the page again restored to 6 and has been that way since. Thank you for showing your concern for me. [Msg too long for chat]

Comment: @InanimateBeing I am not sure what you meant by "As moderator probing possibility of bug" - but I am definitely not a moderator (on any Stack Exchange site).

Comment: ohh, sorry, I assumed